# Why does my server keep creating new files with 0640 permissions in my PHP fwrite?

Tags: php, permissions, fopen, chmod, fwrite

I'm using a simple `fopen("w")` and `fwrite` setup to write a new file on my server. Recently, this has been arbitrarily assigning 0640 permissions to these files, which means I can't view them from a browser. But it's not happening every time. Can anybody tell me why? What I'm missing here? Here's my code:

```
if ($file=fopen("$filesDir/$yr/$mo/{$tempFile[0]}.xml","wb")) {
    if(fwrite($file,$output,strlen($output))) {
        $success="YES";
        $message="File successfully built.";
    } else {
        $message="Could not write XML file.";
    }
} else {
    $message="Could not open file.";
}
```

Comment: Did you try to manually change chmod with PHP after the first write ? In your code, you use `fopen("wb")` and not only `w`, is it normal ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.chmod.php

Comment: I can chmod after I've first written it, but what's strange is that it's not happening every time, and until recently it wasn't happening at all. Some files will be immediately readable, 644, while others in the same folder aren't.

Comment: And `wb` should, by my understanding (gathered from the same site you linked to), just leave `$output` alone as binary instead of trying to make it a certain type of text. `$output` is UTF-8, so I figured that would be the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to guess that it might have something to do with the umask, or the current permissions of the directory that you are creating the file in. Try adding sticky groups to the directory and keeping the group www-data or apache (depending on your install)

Comment: Would that cause files to have different permissions seemingly randomly, despite being in the same folder?

Comment: Why it would be setting them to seeming different permissions is beyond me, but if you give it something to go by, I don't think it would be random anymore.

Comment: OK, then … hahah, this may sound silly, but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: been awhile since ive done this, might be wrong but, try this
find ./nameofdir -type d -exec sudo chmod g+s {} \;
sudo chgrp -R www-data nameofdir

Comment: I tried that verbatim, with my directory instead of nameofdir of course, and it's just saying Invalid Command. I'm just doing this through OSX's Terminal... Also I'm not entirely sure what that stuff means. I mean I know chmod, and I've seen sudo before, but that's about it.

Comment: ahh, see i assumed u were using ubuntu or something. im not sure how to do that on Terminal, i would have to say the best method now would just be to chmod it after u create it

sadly i do not own a mac :/

Comment: I'm using Terminal to get into what I believe is an Apache server elsewhere. The strange thing is, i was having this problem somewhere else and I decided to just chmod after writing the file every time, as a lazy shortcut, and that apparently isn't working now either.

Comment: id check to make sure everything has a group ownership by apache

Comment: As far as I understand it the folder in which all of this is taking place has rwxrwxr-- ownership (774). I've got it now so that as soon as it's built the file it automatically chmods the file so that it has the proper permissions, and that is STILL not doing the trick. Any thoughts? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: so they are still getting created with 640 and chmod isnt doing anything?

Comment: It looks like I was actually coding the chmod wrong, so that solves that problem. I was trying to chmod the string by accident. So I think that's the easiest workaround. But I'm still annoyed that I can't figure out what was causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: my guess is its some sort of umask problem, but i dont know a lot about the system ur running on/with

Answer (score 0):

It does this by default because PHP assumes that you are going to read the file again.  Or, in this case write to it.  You might be able to change the default settings in the php.ini file.